# How to convert MS Word Typeset to MathJax?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I've been a pretty heavy Ms Word Math user and usually I just do all my work in there and export as PDFs (people can barely tell the difference). I heard also that LaTeX is converted into a PDF which has me curious if there is a way to take a starting PDF or Ms Word Math Doc and convert it to LaTeX or prefarably MathJax (for use in this site).

Comment: I found a MS Word to Latex Converter online... so now the question of MathJax is all that remains

Comment: Would you care to share which converter you found? Answer your question and accept it :-)

Comment: These questions are somewhat related (but not exactly the same): [I want to convert equations from Word to Latex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6736/i-want-to-convert-equations-from-word-to-latex) and [Openoffice formula into math.stackexchange post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/openoffice-formula-into-math-stackexchange-post).

Comment: And you can also try to have a look at TeX.SE; for example in the questions mentioned [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6736/i-want-to-convert-equations-from-word-to-latex/6743#6743). Or you could simply browse the questions tagged as [msword](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/msword).

Comment: I voted to close since this doesn't belong in Meta. Meta is for questions about that math.stackexchange website. I think it would be better off on the main site, where it would be on topic as part of "software that mathematicians use"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some options to convert equations in MS Word to mathjax:

- It is possible to copy word equations to mathematica. In mathematica you can [export](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TeXForm.html) expression to latex.
- If you use Mathtype equation editor in word, you have an option to export it as latex.

There is an option in MS Word to export math equations to mathml. I think MSE doesn't allow mathml as input for mathjax. Is there a reason fo this?

The current source code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
```

To support mathml input, I think you only need  this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
```